# how to print without url and datetime by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I want to print the div tag content by javascript by using the following code.

```
var divToPrint1 = $('#PrintDoc').html();
 var newWin = window.open('Share Certificate #001', '', 'width=10px,height=10px');
 newWin.document.open();
 newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print();">' + divToPrint1 + '</body></html>');
 newWin.document.close();
 setTimeout(function () { newWin.close(); }, 10);
```

And print code works fine. But now I want to remove the url, date and title from the printed page by using the javascript code.

Is it possible?
Can you help me to solve the following code?

Comment: What date? Time? URL? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: That is as far as I know completely depending on the browser, and as far as I know there don't exist a standard API for controlling that.

Answer (score 8):

The only online application I have seen that prints without the header and footer is Google Docs. However, after some searching I discovered that gdocs actually generates a pdf file, opens that file, and the prints from there. If that's the best way that Google has found to do it, with all their resources, I would suggest looking that direction.

> *"The headers and footers are put there
>   by your printing subsystem, not by the
>   page or the browser. What that means
>   is, this particular attribute is in
>   the hands of the user. Much like
>   screen resolution or brower width." -
>   [an answer from a webdesign forum](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/15531)*

[This](http://html2pdf.seven49.net/Web/) is a service (paid though) that I found that will generate a pdf via http post. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242389/pdf-render-to-asp-net-web-page-results-in-static-title) is a (seems promising) s.o. question about generating pdfs using asp.net

Comment: +1 for your researched answer. Keep in mind that not all browsers have a PDF plugin. Also, I don't know that there's a consistent way to get a PDF reader to bring up a print dialog.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The quote from the other forum isn't quite right because I found that I could prevent the header/footer from being printed by changing the page settings in the browser's settings. I am looking into the PDF solution since it is not easy for a user to be playing with browser settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">   
@page   
{  
size: auto;   
margin: 0mm;  
}  
body  
{  
background-color:#FFFFFF;   
border: solid 1px black ;  
margin: 0px;  
}                
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists no way to remove the browser's header and footer from printed pages from JavaScript. Either the user will have to turn those off manually or you will have to render the content as a PDF file on the server, as Adobe Reader does not add a header or footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css code snippet

```
<style type="text\css" media="print">
  #myFooter, #myHeader
  {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is solution in the browser side itself.
mentioned the Steps to disable the Header and footer in all the three browsers.

Chrome
Click the Menu icon in the top right corner of the browser.
Click Print.
Uncheck Headers and Footers under the Options section.

Firefox
Click Firefox in the top left corner of the browser.
Place your mouse over Print, the click Page Setup.
Click the Margins & Header/Footer tab.
Change each value under Headers & Footers to --blank--.

Internet Explorer
Click the Gear icon in the top right corner of the browser.
Place your mouse over Print, then click Page Setup.
Change each value under Headers and Footers to -Empty-.